# Regex - Match two specific words with unknown whitespace between them

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to scan multiple files to find a specific pair of strings "CREATE EVENT".

Each instance of this pair of strings has an unknown amount of whitespace between them,

e.g.

```
CREATE EVENT
CREATE  EVENT
CREATE   EVENT
etc.
```

Using Regex in C# I need to replace each match with another string. Something along the lines of:

```
lines = Regex.Replace(lines, "CREATE" + unknownWhiteSpace + "EVENT", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I have tried a few combinations using \s (example below) but can't seem to figure out the correct syntax:

```
lines = Regex.Replace(lines, "([CREATE])" + @"\s+" + "([EVENT])", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You're really close. Good attempt. Just remove the brackets from the words you're looking for: `([CREATE])` and `([EVENT])` => `(CREATE)` and `(EVENT)`. The brackets in regex will match any of the characters in them. So `[CREATE]` matches `C`, `R`, `E`, `A`, or `T`. Removing them matches the whole word `CREATE`.

Comment: You can also perform a replace with `(?<=CREATE)\s+(?=EVENT)` without having to reference the matched group values. This regex ensure what precedes the spaces matches `CREATE` and that `EVENT` succeeds it (without matching or capturing those explicitly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Regex.Replace(x,"CREATE +EVENT", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Working for me in this code:

```
    var x = "CREATE EVENT";
    var y = "CREATE  EVENT";
    var z = "CREATE   EVENT";
    x = Regex.Replace(x,"CREATE +EVENT", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    y = Regex.Replace(y, "CREATE +EVENT", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    z = Regex.Replace(z, "CREATE +EVENT", "CHANGE EVENT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You probably want to change `*`(zero to many) to `+` (one to many). Because it is also matching "one" word too: "CREATEEVENT"

Comment: Thank you fixed up didn't test with no spaces.